# Add indval values on a multivariate regression tree

Tags: r, multivariate-testing, cart-analysis

I used the mvpart package in R to generate a multivariate regression tree. To determine the indicator species responsible for the split, I used the `indval` command in the `labdsv` package.

My question is, how do I insert my indicator species into my regression tree?

[image]

Here is the script I used,

mvpart (Regression Tree)

```
mfish <- mvpart(as.matrix(fisheries.hell[, 2:34]) ~ Time + 
              Fishing.gear +
              Fishing.vessel + Fishing.ground +
              Fishing.hours + Fishing.days, fisheries.wide,
              method="mrt", xv="pick", which="4",
              xvmult=100, bars=FALSE)
```

indval

```
mfish.indval$indcls[which(mfish.indval$pval <= 0.05)]
```